# Plugin to customize home page

Tags: 7

i would like to know of there's a plugin to let an authentified user customize his home page by moving and adding predifined widgets like (agenda, events ..), using drag and drop like iGoogle.

i'm still drupal newbie, any advices are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homebox module makes that reasonably easy to do, worth a look: https://drupal.org/project/homebox

Details from its project page:

> Homebox allows site administrators to create dashboards for their users, using blocks as widgets. Blocks in a Homebox page are resizeable, and reorderable by dragging.
>
> Homebox is currently used on Drupal.org for the 'Your Dashboard' feature.